# How to convert seconds to minutes and hours in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a count of seconds stored in variable `seconds`. I want to convert for example 1439 seconds to 23 minutes and 59 seconds. And if the time is greater than 1 hour (for example 9432 seconds), to 2 hours, 37 minutes and 12 seconds.

How can I achieve this?

I'm thinking of:

```
var sec, min, hour;

if(seconds<3600){
    var a = Math.floor(seconds/60); //minutes
    var b = seconds%60; //seconds

    if (b!=1){
        sec = "seconds";
    }else{
        sec = "second";
    }

    if(a!=1){
        min = "minutes";
    }else{
        min = "minute";
    }

    $('span').text("You have played "+a+" "+min+" and "+b+" "+sec+".");
}else{
        var a = Math.floor(seconds/3600); //hours
    var x = seconds%3600;
    var b = Math.floor(x/60); //minutes
    var c = seconds%60; //seconds

     if (c!=1){
        sec = "seconds";
    }else{
        sec = "second";
    }

    if(b!=1){
        min = "minutes";
    }else{
        min = "minute";
    }

    if(c!=1){
        hour = "hours";
    }else{
        hour = "hour";
    }

    $('span').text("You have played "+a+" "+hour+", "+b+" "+min+" and "+c+" "+sec+".");
}
```

But that's a lot of code, and it has to be calculated each second. How can I shrink this up?

Comment: I answered this here: [how to convert minutes to days,hours,minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751073/how-to-convert-minutes-to-days-hours-minutes/2751143#2751143)

Comment: @RomainHippeau hi! Yes, my code works, but it really big, I'm looking to a way to shrink it (:

Comment: you can use some library such as dateformat.

Comment: Are you worried that it's large, or that it's slow? If the former, you can do a bit of refactoring and use a minifier; if the latter, it is really not slow: worrying about doing this each second is like worrying you shouldn't toss your bubblegum into trash because the junkyard might run out of space.

Comment: @Amadan If it isn't slow then great! I want to shrink it because it's too large, just to make it more compact and use less space, but I don't want to minify it. I'm really bad with shorthands but I was aiming towards that!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for code review.

Comment: Stack Overflow is primarily for question about problems with code (i.e. the code doesn't work), not for improving working code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting seconds into HH:MM:SS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539028/converting-seconds-into-hhmmss)

Answer (score 255, accepted):

I think you would find [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539028/converting-seconds-into-hhmmss) very helpful.

You modify the display format to fit your needs with something like this -

```
function secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hour, " : " hours, ") : "";
    var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " minute, " : " minutes, ") : "";
    var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " second" : " seconds") : "";
    return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
}
```

Comment: This is great! What are the statements used to get the display strings called? ('h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hour, " : " hours, ") : ""')

Comment: Hi @BrandonPillay - not sure if you've researched or not, but those statements are ternary operations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Using this code, passing in 0 returns a blank string, 60 returns `1 minute, `, and 3600 returns `1 hour, `

Comment: I have made some adjustment for commas & time abbreviations:

`function secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hr" : " hrs") + (m > 0 || s > 0 ? ", ":"") : "";
    var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " min" : " mins") + (s > 0 ? ", ":"") : "";
    var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " sec" : " secs") : "";


    return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
}`

Comment: Based on ßikrant's, I have taken the liberty of also adding the DAYS:
function sec2dhms(x) {x=Number(x);
var d=Math.floor(x / (24*3600));
var h=Math.floor(x % (3600*24) / 3600 );
var m=Math.floor(x % 3600 / 60);
var s=Math.floor(x % 3600 % 60);
var dDisplay=d>0? d + (d==1? " day" : " days") + (h>0 || m > 0 || s > 0 ? ", ":"") : "";
var hDisplay=h>0? h + (h==1? " hr" : " hrs") + (m > 0 || s > 0 ? ", ":"") : "";
var mDisplay=m>0? m + (m==1? " min" : " mins") + (s > 0 ? ", ":"") : "";
var sDisplay=s>0? s + (s==1? " sec" : " secs") : "";
return dDisplay + hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay;}

Answer (score 29):

```js
function toTime(seconds) {
  var date = new Date(null);
  date.setSeconds(seconds);
  return date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
}

console.log(toTime(1500)) //'00:25:00'
```

The builtin [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) can simplify the required code

```
 toTime(seconds) {
       var date = new Date(null);
       date.setSeconds(seconds);
       return date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
    }
```

Comment: This seems to save a lot of code, are there drawbacks to using this method?  Why are other answers preferred?

Comment: This MUST be the selected answer.  No modules needed, as `Date` is standard, and it does the exact conversion requested. It seems that people know jQuery better than the language itself.

Comment: This does not answer the ops question as to how to format seconds to come out looking like `2 hours, 17 minutes, 14 seconds`. It can't even be trivially used to cut out the pieces, since the resulting `02:17:14` string will have leading zeros (and roll over to all 0s at 24 hours). It's useful code and a good way to solve a similar problem, but if you came here looking for what the op was looking for, this will not help

Comment: this doesn't work if you have 24 hours or more

Comment: instead of extracting only parts of the iso string, you could use toLocaleTimeString and get only the parts you need: `return date.toLocaleTimeString('de-DE', {timeZone: 'UTC'})`

Comment: Instead of `.substr(11, 8)` use `.slice(11, 19)` (or @honk31's suggestion). [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) is deprecated.

Answer (score 16):

You can try this, i have used this successfully in the past
You should be able to add the minutes and seconds on easily

```
function secondsToTime(secs)
{
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));

    var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

    var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    var seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);

    var obj = {
        "h": hours,
        "m": minutes,
        "s": seconds
    };
    return obj;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s5gdxgnp/)

You can change the object to

```
var obj = {
        "h": hours + " hours",
        "m": minutes + " minutes",
        "s": seconds + " seconds"
    };
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm probably a bit late but you can achieve this kind of things using

https://momentjs.com/

`myVar = moment(myVar).format('HH:mm');`

moment provides A LOT of format for hours / dates etc.

Comment: Never too late, but I definitely think that depending on the use case you can add momentjs but just to add a whole library for something as small as this ... seems a bit much don't you think. But yes it will get the job done

Comment: moment.js is great, but to format seconds instead of a moment object, you have to use `moment.duration()`. For example: `${moment.duration(Number(myVar), 'seconds').hours()}:${moment.duration(Number(myVar), 'seconds').minutes()}:${moment.duration(Number(myVar), 'seconds').seconds()}`

Comment: This is great, but without specifiying the timezone it will add up offset ours, so you should go with: `moment.utc(myVar)...`

Comment: don't forget that the project authors of moment.js themselves broadly no longer recommend you use it: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Answer (score 8):

Try this, Convert SEC to H:M:S.

```
function convertTime(sec) {
    var hours = Math.floor(sec/3600);
    (hours >= 1) ? sec = sec - (hours*3600) : hours = '00';
    var min = Math.floor(sec/60);
    (min >= 1) ? sec = sec - (min*60) : min = '00';
    (sec < 1) ? sec='00' : void 0;

    (min.toString().length == 1) ? min = '0'+min : void 0;    
    (sec.toString().length == 1) ? sec = '0'+sec : void 0;    

    return hours+':'+min+':'+sec;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A low fat way to do this is:

```
function seconds_to_days_hours_mins_secs_str(seconds)
{ // day, h, m and s
  var days     = Math.floor(seconds / (24*60*60));
      seconds -= days    * (24*60*60);
  var hours    = Math.floor(seconds / (60*60));
      seconds -= hours   * (60*60);
  var minutes  = Math.floor(seconds / (60));
      seconds -= minutes * (60);
  return ((0<days)?(days+" day, "):"")+hours+"h, "+minutes+"m and "+seconds+"s";
}
```

Thus

```
> seconds_to_days_hours_mins_secs_str(9432+60*60*24)
'1 days, 2h, 37m and 12s'
```

This is easy to understand and extend as needed.

Answer (score 4):

I found Wilson Lee's and Brian's code super useful! Here is how I adapted their code:

```
function formatTime(serverTimeinSeconds, elementId)
{ /* This converts seconds into days, hours, minutes and seconds timestring.
     Requires JQuery if elementId argument is provided */
  seconds = Math.floor(Number(serverTimeinSeconds));
  days = Math.floor(seconds / (24*60*60));
  seconds -= Math.floor(days    * (24*60*60));
  hours    = Math.floor(seconds / (60*60));
  seconds -= Math.floor(hours   * (60*60));
  minutes  = Math.floor(seconds / (60));
  seconds -= Math.floor(minutes * (60));

  dDisplay = days > 0 ? days + (days == 1 ? ' day, ' : ' days, ') : '';
  hDisplay = hours > 0 ? hours + (hours == 1 ? ' hour, ' : ' hours, ') : '';
  mDisplay = minutes > 0 ? minutes + (minutes == 1 ? ' minute, ' : ' minutes, ') : '';
  sDisplay = seconds > 0 ? seconds + (seconds == 1 ? ' second' : ' seconds') : '';

  if (elementId != null) {
    if (serverTimeinSeconds < 60) {
        $(elementId).css('font-size', '15px');
        $(elementId).html(sDisplay);
    }
    if (serverTimeinSeconds >= 60 && serverTimeinSeconds < 3600) {
        $(elementId).css('font-size', '15px');
        $(elementId).html(mDisplay + sDisplay);
    }
    if (serverTimeinSeconds >= 3600 && serverTimeinSeconds < 86400) {
        $(elementId).css('font-size', '12px');
        $(elementId).html(hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay);
    }
    if (serverTimeinSeconds >= 86400 && serverTimeinSeconds !== Infinity) {
        $(elementId).css('font-size', '8px');
        $(elementId).html(dDisplay + hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay);
    }
  }
  return dDisplay + hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 const formatter = (seconds = 0) => {
  const d = Number(secondsAmount);
  const h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
  const m = Math.floor((d % 3600) / 60);
  const s = Math.floor((d % 3600) % 60);
  const hDisplay = h > 0 ? `${h.toString().length > 1 ? `${h}` : `${0}${h}`}` : '00';
  const mDisplay = m > 0 ? `${m.toString().length > 1 ? `${m}` : `${0}${m}`}` : '00';
  const sDisplay = s > 0 ? `${s.toString().length > 1 ? `${s}` : `${0}${s}`}` : '00';
  return `${hDisplay}:${mDisplay}:${sDisplay}`;
};
```

Will return this format human readable format **00:00:00**

Comment: Simple and functional!

Answer (score 3):

```
Please install moment js after that import it,

import moment from 'moment'

let dateForm = (arg) => {
    return moment.unix(arg).utc().format('H [hours,] m [minutes and] s [seconds]');
}

console.log(dateForm(11));
// 0 hours, 0 minutes and 11 seconds
```

console.log(dateForm(1*60*60));
// 1 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds

Comment: This seems a little unnecessarily `extra`

Comment: this is the perfect answer. can we have a condition that if hours is 0, don't display it

Answer (score 3):

for having the result with the time format " 00:00:00 " I added some changes to it.

```
function secondsToHms(seconds) {

  let d = Number(seconds);

  if(d <= 0){
     return '00:00:00'
  }else{
    let h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    let m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    let s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    let hDisplay = h <= 9 ? '0'+ h+':' : h+ ":";
    let mDisplay = m <= 9 ? '0'+ m+':' : m+ ":";
    let sDisplay = s <= 9 ? '0'+ s : s;


    return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 

  }}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it:

```js
const formatDuration = totalSeconds => {
  const hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600)
  const minutes = Math.floor((totalSeconds % 3600) / 60)
  const seconds = totalSeconds - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60

  return [`${hours}h`, `${minutes}m`, `${seconds}s`]
    .filter(item => item[0] !== '0')
    .join(' ')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Built off R4nc1d's answer:

```
function secondsToTime(secs){
  var h = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));

  var divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
  var m = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);

  var divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
  var s = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);

  return `${h?`${h}:`:""}${m?`${m}:${s}`:`${s}s`}`
}
```

This will return a human readable answer which looks like this. I used this for displaying the length of music tracks

```
time = secondsToTime(5)   
console.log(time)         // 5s
time = secondsToTime(50)  
console.log(time)         // 50s
time = secondsToTime(500) 
console.log(time)         // 8:20
time = secondsToTime(5000)
console.log(time)         // 1:23:20
```

Answer (score 1):

@pkerckhove has already mentioned `moment` as a great library to work with dates and times, and you can also use `moment` to directly format the seconds into OP's desired format, i.e.:

```
import moment from 'moment'

const myVar = 1439
console.log(
    moment.unix(myVar).utc().format('H [hours,] m [minutes and] s [seconds]')
)
```

Will result in: `0 hours, 23 minutes and 59 seconds` and,

```
import moment from 'moment'

const myVar = 9432
console.log(
    moment.unix(myVar).utc().format('H [hours,] m [minutes and] s [seconds]')
)
```

Will result in: `2 hours, 37 minutes and 12 seconds`

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/

Answer (score 1):

This method also works with a negative amount of time:

```
function CalculateTime(sec){

    if(sec >= 0){
        var h = Math.floor(sec / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(sec % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(sec % 3600 % 60);
    }
    else{
        var h = Math.ceil(sec / 3600);
    var m = Math.ceil(sec % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.ceil(sec % 3600 % 60);
    }

    var hDisplay = h !== 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hour, " : " hours") + (m != 0 || s > 0 ? ", ":"") : "";
    var mDisplay = m !== 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " minute, " : " minutes")  + (s != 0 ? " ":""): "";
    var sDisplay = s !== 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " second" : " seconds") : "";
    return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :D

```
secondsToHms(d) {
        d = Number(d);
        var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
        var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
        var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

        var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? "" : "") : "";
        var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? "" : "") : "";
        var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? "" : "") : "";
        if (hDisplay != "") {
            return (hDisplay.length > 1 ? hDisplay : '0' + hDisplay) + ":" + (mDisplay.length > 1 ? mDisplay : '0' + mDisplay) + ":" + (sDisplay.length > 1 ? sDisplay : '0' + sDisplay);
        }
        else if (mDisplay != "") {
            return (mDisplay.length > 1 ? mDisplay : '0' + mDisplay) + ":" + (sDisplay.length > 1 ? sDisplay : '0' + sDisplay);
        }
        else if (sDisplay != "") {
            return "00:" + (sDisplay.length > 1 ? sDisplay : '0' + sDisplay);
        }
        return "00:00"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the popular [date-fns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns) library

```
import { format, setSeconds, startOfDay } from 'date-fns'

export const hourMinSec = (secs: number, showHour = false): string => {

  const tmpDate: Date = startOfDay(new Date())
  const date: Date = setSeconds(tmpDate, secs)
  const hour: number = date.getHours()
  const hasHour: boolean = !!hour

  if (hasHour && !showHour) console.warn('hourMinSec is hiding a non zero hour')

  const strFormat: string = showHour ? 'H:mm:ss' : 'm:ss'
  return format(date, strFormat)
}
```

OR the same code with a more functional approach (adding lodash flow in the mix)

```
import { setSeconds, startOfDay } from 'date-fns/fp'
import { format } from 'date-fns'
import { flow } from 'lodash-es'

export const hourMinSec = (secs: number, showHour = false): string => {
  const date: Date = flow(startOfDay, setSeconds(secs))(new Date())
  const hour: number = date.getHours()
  const hasHour: boolean = !!hour

  if (hasHour && !showHour) console.warn('hourMinSec is hiding a non zero hour')

  const strFormat: string = showHour ? 'H:mm:ss' : 'm:ss'
  return format(date, strFormat)
}
```

Usage:

```
hourMinSec(100)         //    1:40
hourMinSec(3700)        //    1:40 // will warn in logs that a non zero hour is hidden
hourMinSec(100, true)   // 0:01:40
hourMinSec(3700, true)  // 1:01:40
```

This met my needs but you could adapt this by changing the `showHour = false` parameter to be a `strFormat = 'm:ss'` parameter instead to support more flexible formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
const minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60);
const seconds = Math.floor(duration - minutes * 60);

const time = `${minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}
             :${seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds}`; // result: 02:23
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Another option with inline comments:

```js
// Seconds to Days Hours Minutes Seconds function
const sec2DHMS = s => {
  // D/Hr/Min from Sec calculation.
  // Both Hr and Min timeframes have 60 and D have 24 fractions, so we
  // can create one logic for them. We divide Min/Sec on 60 to find out
  // whole Hr/Min, then calculate Sec of whole Hr/Min, then calculate
  // difference between input Sec and Sec of whole Hr/Min to find out
  // fraction of Hr/Min. With D we do same thing, but with 24 divider.
  const calc = (v, f) => { const x = Math.trunc(v/f); return [x, v-x*f]; },
    [m, sr] = calc(s, 60),
    [h, mr] = calc(m, 60),
    [d, hr] = calc(h, 24);
  return { d, h, m, s, hr, mr, sr };
}

// Test all data
const { d, h, m, s, hr, mr, sr } = sec2DHMS(90061);
console.log(`${d} d, ${hr} hr, ${mr} min, ${sr} sec are whole ${h} hr, or ${m} min, or ${s} sec.`);

// So, if you need only Hr/Min/Sec
console.log(`90061 sec is ${h} hr, ${mr} min, ${sr} sec`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/37096512/588759

```js
function secondsToHHMMss(seconds: number) {
  if (typeof seconds === 'undefined') throw new Error('seconds is undefined');
  const d = Math.abs(seconds);
  const h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
  const m = Math.floor((d % 3600) / 60);
  const s = Math.floor((d % 3600) % 60);
  return [h, m, s].map((n) => String(n).padStart(2, '0')).join(':');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

useCountDown Hook

```
// useCountDown.js

import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const useCountDown = (minutes) => {
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(minutes * 60)

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(seconds - 1)
    }, 1000)

    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [seconds])

  return getReturnValues2(seconds)
}

const getReturnValues2 = (countDown) => {

  const minutes = Math.floor(countDown / 60)
  const seconds = countDown % 60

  return `${padTo2Digits(minutes)}:${padTo2Digits(seconds)}`
}

function padTo2Digits(num) {
  return num.toString().padStart(2, "0")
}

export default useCountDown
```

How to use?

```
//React Component

import useCountDown from '../hooks/useCountDown'

function App() {
   const countDown = useCountDown(5) // 5 Minutes
   return (
       <h1> {countDown} </h1>   // MM:SS
   )
}
```

You can tweak as per your needs.

Comment: nice approach using hooks, this should be accepted as answer

Comment: @ChiragJoshi No, this shouldn't be accepted as the answer. OP clearly asked for a JavaScript solution (implying vanilla JS), and not an answer that relies on React, jQuery, Vue or whatever.

Answer (score -2):

Convert to H:M

```
Number(moment.duration(Number(37320), 'seconds').hours()+'.'+moment.duration(Number(37320),'seconds').minutes())
```