# Correct syntax to apply a method within render () using arrow function

Tags: reactjs, callback, arguments, date-formatting

I found this [great method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37096512/3926863) on Stackoverflow to convert duration from ss into  hh.mm.ss and  I tried to call it within the render () section of the page. Many attempts, but not yet successful. I think I am missing something in the syntax of the arrow function, but can't find out what.

This is the method I slightly edited for my purpose:

```
formatTime(duration) {
    d = Number(duration);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    var hDisplay = h > 0 ? h + (h == 1 ? " hour, " : " hours, ") : "";
    var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? " minute, " : " minutes, ") : "";
    var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? " second" : " seconds") : "";
    return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay;
    }
```

And this is my `render()` section, where I would like to call `formatTime()`, passing  `song.duration` as an argument of the method ([full code here](https://jsfiddle.net/m67chwbz/)):

```
render() {
     return (

//[...] 

     <td {() => this.formatTime(song.duration)}> 
     {formatTime(song.duration)} </td>

//[...] 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
<td> {this.formatTime(song.duration)} </td>
```

Because of the following reasons:

1- Its a class method so you need to use `this.functionName()` to access the function.

2- You are normally calling the function and it is returning some content/value which you want to render so arrow function is not required.

---

Check this answer for more details about [when javascript bind or arrow function is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391288/why-is-javascript-bind-necessary)

Comment: thank you and great link! I'm still getting an error "'d' is not defined" ... I assume this is related to passing the argument. I tried to put `song.duration` instead of `duration` as an argument, but I am still getting the error.

Comment: its because you are directly assigning value to variable d without declaring it. use this line: `var d = Number(duration);`, in the answer from where you copied that snippet, `d` is a function parameter thats why no declaration.