# How would I be able to convert days into hours?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debugging

Right now, I could display days hours minutes and seconds withtout a problem.  But what I want to do this time is take the days, convert them into hours and display it.

For example, if I set my timer to be three days from now, I want it to display `72 hours 20 minutes 30 seconds`.  Notice how days aren't in the picture, I don't want to do display `3 days`.

How would I be able to achieve this?

```
var countDownDate  = new Date("6 June 2019 15:00:00");


        var options = {
            hour: 'numeric',
            minute: 'numeric',
            hour12: true
        };

        var countDate = countDownDate.toLocaleString('en-US', options);
        console.log(countDate);

        var now            = new Date().getTime();
        var timeDifference = countDownDate - now;
        var oneDay         = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

        var days           = Math.floor(timeDifference / (oneDay));
        var hours          = Math.floor((timeDifference % (oneDay)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes        = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds        = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        // Displays the clock counting down
        document.querySelector("#timer").innerHTML = `
        <span>${hours}   </br> hours</span>
        <span>${minutes} </br> minutes</span>
        <span>${seconds} </br> seconds!</span>`;

        if(timeDifference < 0) { 
            clearInterval(timer); 
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Expired"; 
        }
```

Comment: Just don't display days and multiple the days by 24 to get the number of hours? Then add that to the remaining hours?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert seconds to minutes and hours in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096367/how-to-convert-seconds-to-minutes-and-hours-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

each day equals 24 hours, so just add 24*days to hours:)

a better solution would be to calculate hours like that:

```
hours = Math.floor(timeDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60));
```

Comment: each day is not equal to 24hours. Sometimes may be 23 hours to 25 hours for Daylight saving time (DST) . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time