# How create custome pipe to convert seconde to hours en minutes data from API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pipe

how to make a custom pipe in angular 8 to convert second to hours and minutes.

thanks.

```
<div class="col-2" *ngFor="let movie of moviesList">
  <div class="movie">
    {{ movie.attributes.title }}
    <img [src]="movie.thumbnails.small">
    {{ movie.attributes.duration }} <== second
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: create a pipe class and implement the `transform()` method. checkout angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes

Comment: yes i already tried that but i dont understand how i can use the Transform(). to convert Second to Hours & Minutes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37096367/1160794

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a pipe with a name like `FormatTime`

**format-time.pipes.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'formatTime'})
export class FormatTime implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): string {
    return new Date(value * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8)
  }
}
```

**Import and add it to your declarations in the module**

```
...
import { FormatTime } from './format-time.pipes';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, FormatTime ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Template**

```
<div class="col-2" *ngFor="let movie of moviesList">
  <div class="movie">
    {{ movie.attributes.title }}
    <img [src]="movie.thumbnails.small">
    {{ movie.attributes.duration | formatTime }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pipe like below,

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'secondsTransform'
})
export class SecondsTransformPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor() {}

    transform(value: number): string {
        let minutes: number = Math.trunc(value/60);
        let hours: number = 0;
        let seconds: number = value - (minutes*60);

        if (minutes >= 60) {
          hours = Math.trunc(minutes/60);
          minutes = minutes - (hours*60);
        }

        let response: string = "";

        if (hours > 0) {
          response = response + hours + " hours ";
        } 

        if (minutes > 0) {
          response = response + minutes + " minutes ";
        }

        if (seconds > 0) {
          response = response + seconds + " seconds";
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Import the pipe in the module and use it in html as `{{seconds|secondsTransform}}`

You can refer the below sample which uses pipe to show the seconds in Hours/Minutes/Seconds,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7jte9o