# Day, Hour, Min Calculation from the Minutes

Tags: android, kotlin, time, duration

The Requirement is as below to display Day, Hour, and Minute from **Total Minutes**:

I am getting the Minutes from the Hardware device.

**6050 minutes** is displayed as: **4d 5h** (it is 4 days 4 hours and 50 minutes, 50 minutes we round to 1 hour)

**6090 minutes** is displayed as: **4d 6h** (it is 4 days 5 hours and 30 minutes, 30 minutes we round to 1 hour)

**6089 minutes** is displayed as **4d 5h** (it is 4 days 5 hours and 29 minutes, 29 minutes we round to 0 hours)

**Other thing to take care** is **0d 0h and 0m** should be display as **0m**.

**One more thing is** : If total hour is > 100, it should display without minute.

So far I have tried to achive it as below but not getting proper output:

```
fun minutesToDaysHoursMinutes(time: Double): String? {
     val hourFromMinute: Double = time * 60.0

     val d: Duration = Duration.ofMinutes(time.toLong())
     val days: Long = d.toDays()
     val hours: Long = d.toHours() % 24
     val minutes: Long = d.toMinutes() % 60

     if (hourFromMinute > 100) {
         if (minutes >= 30) {
             if (days == 0L && hours != 0L) {
                 return String.format("%2dh", hours)
             }
             if (days != 0L && hours == 0L) {
                 return String.format("%2dd", days)
             }
             return String.format("%2dd %2dh", days, (hours + 1))
         } else {
             if (days == 0L && hours != 0L) {
                 return String.format("%2dh", hours)
             }
             if (days != 0L && hours == 0L) {
                 return String.format("%2dd", days)
             }
             if (days == 0L && hours == 0L) {
                 return String.format("%2dm", minutes)
             }
             return String.format("%2dd %2dh", days, hours)
         }
     } else {
         var stringDays = "" + days
         if (stringDays.toInt()<=0) {
             stringDays = ""
         } else {
             stringDays = stringDays + "d"
         }
         var stringHours = "" + hours
         if (stringHours.toInt()<=0) {
             stringHours = ""
         } else {
             stringHours = stringHours + "h"
         }
         var stringMinutes = "" + minutes
         if (stringMinutes.toInt()<=0) {
             stringMinutes = "0m"
         } else {
             stringMinutes = stringMinutes + "m"
         }
         return stringDays + " " + stringHours + " " + stringMinutes
     }
```

I can display proper values but Is there any better way to do so ?
Thank you.

Comment: "not getting proper output" and "I can display proper values". you seem to contradict yourself? Are you getting the right output or not? And if not, what is wrong with it? Or what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Calculation is okay. If there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: @IvoBeckers edited question. please check.

Comment: Did you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751073/how-to-convert-minutes-to-days-hours-minutes

Comment: *"If total hour is > 100, it should display without minute"* — But you are already rounding to hours, does this mean that you always see 0m if the minutes are shown? Or did you just mean: *"If total hour is > 100, it should display without **hour**"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have many if statements where roughly the same code is repeated. Also, your `minutesToDaysHoursMinutes` method is doing two things: rounding and formatting the output.

I think you should put these two responsibilities into two separate methods.

#### The rounding

First, you could do the founding as follows:

```java
Duration roundFromMinutesToHours(double minutes) {
    var duration = Duration.ofMinutes((long) minutes);
    long hoursToAdd = (duration.toMinutesPart() < 30 ? 0 : 1);
    return duration.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS).plusHours(hoursToAdd);
}
```

This method accepts the number of minutes, and then rounds up or down to hours, discarding the minutes value. Note that this method uses `Duration::toMinutesPart`, which has been available since Java 9. `toMinutesPart` doesn't return the *total* number of minutes, like `toMinutes()`, but instead, returns the number of minutes *within the hour*. Note that this method returns a `Duration` with a rounded-to-full-hours value.

Now you have a nice rounded Duration, which you can use in the following method.

#### The formatting

Then you could write the formatting of the `Duration` as follows:

```java
String formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    if (duration.isZero()) {
        return "0m";
    }

    var result = String.format("%sd %sh", duration.toDays(), duration.toHoursPart());
    if (duration.toHours() <= 100) {
        result += " 0m";
    }
    return result;
}
```

If the duration is 0 (thus originaly < 30 minutes), then return "0m". Otherwise, return either "*x*d *y*h" or "*x*d *y*h *z*m", where *x*, *y* and *z* are the days, hours and minutes respectively, based on whether the total number of hours is greater than 100.

Comment: Can you please add the whole code?

Comment: @JaiminModi The whole code? This is all you need. Simply get the desired result with `String result = formatDuration(roundFromMinutesToHours(yourMinutesInput))`.